# Changes needed in Entity Framework to change database engine

Tags: database, entity-framework

Let's assume I have created an EF application that depends on MSSQL Server, and now I would like to change my DB engine to Oracle, what are the amount of changes needed to do this change?

do I have to just change the connection string and database provider in the config file?

OR

I will have to create different DBContext class and other changes that will impact the code on higher layers that are using this DBContext class?

Comment: it depends on how you set up your project. You can definitely keep both providers in your config and access two differing dbms simultaneously, because I did that as well. you may also use differing dbcontext. for the use of another dbms by changing connection string + config you need to touch 3 places in the code I think. I always had a provider parameter in my dbcontext constructor, which simply resulted in another connection string. with both providers installed, it worked without much hassle.